# Change menu hot keys in Destiny 2

Tags: pc, destiny-2

I'm playing Destiny 2 on PC and have rebound all my hotkeys to the other side of the keyboard. I'm left handed and use O K L ; for my movement with my left hand on the mouse.

My problem is that Q, E L and D are reserved for navigating the menu and bizarrely do not just follow my bindings.

The menu system works super well with my pad but it is a pain in the neck for me, especially the milestone tab.

Is there any way to change these keys?

Comment: This update about editing the CVARS might be helpful. https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/46407